# How to keep Skype open on multiple virtual desktops on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, skype

I am using Windows' 10 new virtual desktop feature (which is neat).
Now, I have Skype running on the virtual desktop 1 and switch over to virtual desktop 2. Whenever I get a new message and try to open it, I get taken back to virtual desktop 1.
Running another instance of Skype on desktop 2 does not work either (I get taken back to desktop 1 again).
Is there any way I can have Skype running on multiple virtual desktop at once?

Comment: Because Skype actively attempts to prevent multiple instances of itself from running what you want is not possible.

Comment: interestingly, some applications such as gimp will unwantedly put themselves on all desktops simultaneously, so it must be possible somehow. (then again, maybe it's just a lazy/different way of programming gimp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since August 2nd 2016 (Windows 10 anniversary update) it is possible to show apps and their windows on all virtual desktops:

From [the Windows blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/):

> You can now pin a window so it’s available on every desktop. To do this, launch Task View then right-click on the window you want to pin and choose “Show this window on all desktops”. Try pinning Skype or Groove Music so they’re always at your fingertips. And if you have a multi-mon setup, you might enjoy the ability to have your email app on the second monitor no matter which desktop you switch to.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I describe below how one can open as many Skype sessions as required,
but the sessions must be opened with different accounts.

Start the first Skype session as usual, by using the Skype icon.

To launch a second Skype application, press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog, copy-paste the below command into it, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For a 64-bit version of Windows :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
```

For a 32-bit version of Windows :

```
"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
```

You can repeat this process to open a third, fourth, and other additional copies of Skype. Sign into each Skype window with a new account.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc: in my case though, I'd like to use the same account on each virtual desktop

Comment: I don't think that's possible, except maybe by using differing logins on Windows. Even if two logins work it is still problematic, as I know that If you are logged in to the same Skype account on two *differing devices*, an incoming call will ring on both but only the first to answer will be able to participate. You might try to run the second Skype via [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) as another user, or [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no native support in Windows 10 to pin windows to multiple desktops. When the anniversary update comes around (I believe it's August 2nd), this will be possible. You *could* update to an insider preview build if you want it now. It's available from build 14316.

[source](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-pin-an-app-window-to-all-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @harrymc Isn't that what OP wants?

Comment: Yes, you're probably right.